# How to make mpld3 work with seaborn (interactive tooltips)

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, mpld3

I can't seem to get the interactive tooltips powered by mpld3 to work with the fantastic lmplot-like scatter plots from seaborn.

I'd love any pointer on how to get this to work! Thanks!

Example Code:

```
# I'm running this in an ipython notebook.
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, mpld3
mpld3.enable_notebook()
import seaborn as sns


N=10
data = pd.DataFrame({"x": np.random.randn(N),
                     "y": np.random.randn(N), 
                     "size": np.random.randint(20,200, size=N),
                     "label": np.arange(N)
                     })


scatter_sns = sns.lmplot("x", "y", 
           scatter_kws={"s": data["size"]},
           robust=False, # slow if true
           data=data, size=8)
fig = plt.gcf()

tooltip = mpld3.plugins.PointLabelTooltip(fig, labels=list(data.label))
mpld3.plugins.connect(fig, tooltip)

mpld3.display(fig)
```

I'm getting the seaborn plot along with the following error:

```
Javascript error adding output!
TypeError: obj.elements is not a function
See your browser Javascript console for more details.
```

The console shows:

```
TypeError: obj.elements is not a function
    at mpld3_TooltipPlugin.draw (https://mpld3.github.io/js/mpld3.v0.2.js:1161:9)
    at mpld3_Figure.draw (https://mpld3.github.io/js/mpld3.v0.2.js:1400:23)
    at Object.mpld3.draw_figure (https://mpld3.github.io/js/mpld3.v0.2.js:18:9)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (https://mbcomp1:9999/static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js:4:4231), <anonymous>:14:14)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (https://mbcomp1:9999/static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js:4:4231), <anonymous>:15:5)
    at eval (native)
    at Function.x.extend.globalEval (https://mbcomp1:9999/static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js:4:4231)
    at x.fn.extend.domManip (https://mbcomp1:9999/static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js:5:21253)
    at x.fn.extend.append (https://mbcomp1:9999/static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js:5:18822)
    at OutputArea._safe_append (https://mbcomp1:9999/static/notebook/js/outputarea.js:336:26)
outputarea.js:319 Javascript error adding output! TypeError: obj.elements is not a function
    at mpld3_TooltipPlugin.draw (https://mpld3.github.io/js/mpld3.v0.2.js:1161:9)
    at mpld3_Figure.draw (https://mpld3.github.io/js/mpld3.v0.2.js:1400:23)
    at Object.mpld3.draw_figure (https://mpld3.github.io/js/mpld3.v0.2.js:18:9)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (https://mbcomp1:9999/static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js:4:4231), <anonymous>:14:14)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (https://mbcomp1:9999/static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js:4:4231), <anonymous>:15:5)
    at eval (native)
    at Function.x.extend.globalEval (https://mbcomp1:9999/static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js:4:4231)
    at x.fn.extend.domManip (https://mbcomp1:9999/static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js:5:21253)
    at x.fn.extend.append (https://mbcomp1:9999/static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js:5:18822)
    at OutputArea._safe_append (https://mbcomp1:9999/static/notebook/js/outputarea.js:336:26)
outputarea.js:338 TypeError: obj.elements is not a function
    at mpld3_TooltipPlugin.draw (https://mpld3.github.io/js/mpld3.v0.2.js:1161:9)
    at mpld3_Figure.draw (https://mpld3.github.io/js/mpld3.v0.2.js:1400:23)
    at Object.mpld3.draw_figure (https://mpld3.github.io/js/mpld3.v0.2.js:18:9)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (https://mbcomp1:9999/static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js:4:4231), <anonymous>:14:14)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (https://mbcomp1:9999/static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js:4:4231), <anonymous>:15:5)
    at eval (native)
    at Function.x.extend.globalEval (https://mbcomp1:9999/static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js:4:4231)
    at x.fn.extend.domManip (https://mbcomp1:9999/static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js:5:21253)
    at x.fn.extend.append (https://mbcomp1:9999/static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js:5:18822)
    at OutputArea._safe_append (https://mbcomp1:9999/static/notebook/js/outputarea.js:336:26)
outputarea.js:319 Javascript error adding output! TypeError: obj.elements is not a function
    at mpld3_TooltipPlugin.draw (https://mpld3.github.io/js/mpld3.v0.2.js:1161:9)
    at mpld3_Figure.draw (https://mpld3.github.io/js/mpld3.v0.2.js:1400:23)
    at Object.mpld3.draw_figure (https://mpld3.github.io/js/mpld3.v0.2.js:18:9)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (https://mbcomp1:9999/static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js:4:4231), <anonymous>:14:14)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (https://mbcomp1:9999/static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js:4:4231), <anonymous>:15:5)
    at eval (native)
    at Function.x.extend.globalEval (https://mbcomp1:9999/static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js:4:4231)
    at x.fn.extend.domManip (https://mbcomp1:9999/static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js:5:21253)
    at x.fn.extend.append (https://mbcomp1:9999/static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js:5:18822)
    at OutputArea._safe_append (https://mbcomp1:9999/static/notebook/js/outputarea.js:336:26)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that there is an easy way to do this currently.  I can get some of the tooltips to show by replacing your `tooltip` constructor with the following:

```
ax = plt.gca()
pts = ax.get_children()[3]
tooltip = mpld3.plugins.PointLabelTooltip(pts, labels=list(data.label))
```

This only works for the points outside of the uncertainty interval, though.  I think it would be possible to extend `seaborn` to make these points highest in the `zorder` and store them in in the instance somewhere so that you don't need do pull them out of the axis children list.  Perhaps worth a feature request.

Comment: Here is [a notebook showing how it looks](https://gist.github.com/aflaxman/fbadf7772709ef1a8fcc).

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the tooltips to work by using the standard matplotlib scatter on top of the seaborn plot and very low alpha (you can't use zero)

```
data_tip_points = ax.scatter(x_points, y_points, alpha=0.001)
tooltip = plugins.PointLabelTooltip(data_tip_points, labels)
```

It's a bit of a hack, but it works as seen here.

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/bitbucket.org/jeff_mcgehee/cds_presentation_intro/raw/49cc7808ec26adebec94ffa83973bb5db13017d7/CDS%20Intro%20Presentation.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me on `ipython` (no notepad) when saving the figure to file with `mpld3.save_html(fig,"./out.html")`. May be an issue with `ipython` `notepad`/`mpld3` compatibility or `mpld3.display` (which causes an error for me, although I think this is related to an old version of matplotlib on my computer).

The full code which worked for me is,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, mpld3
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

N=10
data = pd.DataFrame({"x": np.random.randn(N),
                     "y": np.random.randn(N), 
                     "size": np.random.randint(20,200, size=N),
                     "label": np.arange(N)
                     })


scatter_sns = sns.lmplot("x", "y", 
           scatter_kws={"s": data["size"]},
           robust=False, # slow if true
           data=data, size=8)
fig = plt.gcf()

tooltip = mpld3.plugins.PointLabelTooltip(fig, labels=list(data.label))
mpld3.plugins.connect(fig, tooltip)

mpld3.save_html(fig,"./out.html")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same error even when exporting to html.
In case this is a version issue.
I am using:
mpld3 0.2
matplotlib 1.4.3
seaborn 0.5.1