# Hover tooltip data in seaborn and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, kaggle

Is it possible to create some kind of hover tooltip from pandas dataframe on a linear regression plot from seaborn library?

More specifically I have this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
dframe=pd.read_csv('pokemon.csv')
sns.lmplot('hp', 'total', dframe)
```

And the result is the linear regression chart. How can I create such a tooltip, that when i hover over one of the dots on the chart, the corresponding value from one of the columns in that `dframe` will be displayed? In this case the name of the Pokemon.

The csv file comes from [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/mylesoneill/pokemon-sun-and-moon-gen-7-stats/downloads/pokemon.csv).

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31480921/how-to-make-mpld3-work-with-seaborn-interactive-tooltips

Comment: This is probably trivially easy with bokeh. Check out the tooltips in bokeh here: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#basic-tooltips

Comment: Hmm So can bookeh be linked to the seaborn chart? Or shall I create a the same chart using bookeh? Im not sure if bookeh has linear regression plotting.

Comment: `bokeh` doesn't implement linear regression directly, no, but you can build it yourself using e.g. `statsmodels`. If you absolutely need interaction of this sort, `bokeh` is the way to go. It's technically possible to do in `matplotlib`, as some answers here have demonstrated in the past, but it's very painful and absolutely not something you want to attempt.

Comment: I actually dont need the linear regression that much but the scatter plot is more what I'm trying to do, will update when done(is bookeh good for that too?)

Comment: This is a very old post but I found another response on Stack Overflow that answers this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908636/possible-to-make-labels-appear-when-hovering-over-a-point-in-matplotlib

Comment: That would be good starting point for me to check if Seaborn has also this feature. I remember that I found something for matplotlib, but tooltips with seaborn did not work in similar way.